# API for maintain the uploaded file versions in .net

Tags: asp.net, api

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio and SQL Server for development.

The problem is initially i upload a file after some time if i upload the another file instead of existing one, then i want to maintain the previous file and also the version are created automatically each time while upload a new file.

Is there any **opensource .net API** is available to maintain the files with version?

Because i want to show the old files to user when they select roll back option.

**Any suggestions** please give me how to figure out this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a database lying around, this can be done with two tables (setting aside the discussion about where to keep actual binary content):

```
File
----
ID int
Name string(200)
MimeType string(200)
LastRevisionID references Revision.ID, nullable

Revision
----
FileID references File.ID
Content varbinary(max)
```

When a file is initially uploaded:

```
begin tran
insert into File ... values ...
insert into Revision .... values ....
update File set LastRevisionID = @lastInsertedRevisionID where ID = @id
commit tran
```

When a file is updated, first `select * from File where Name = @name`, remember the `LastRevisionID` as `@lastRevisionID` and then:

```
 begin tran
 insert into Revision .... values ....
 update File set LastRevisionID = @lastInsertedRevisionID
   where ID = @id and LastRevisionID = @lastRevisionID
 commit tran
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try your answer for image files. My file types are image, audio, video and 3D (.Ecoz). Is there possible to store audio,video and 3D files in database?

Comment: @Asha Theoretically, you can store virtually anything -- as long as it fits. Practially, databases are better suited for non-binary (as in non-BLOB) data.

Comment: Thanks @Anton is it possible to store the files as folder structure like tortoise svn?

Comment: @Asha Sure it is. You can have a directory per file and then store each version as a new file in this directory. Not the most space-efficient approach, but it will work.